# Edge pointing to an edge?

Tags: orientdb

In OrientDB 3.0.x (x>5) is it possible to have an edge, one of end of which is also an edge? It seems possible, but not explained in the docs:

```
        --Define vertex A,B,C
        create class testVertexA extends V;
        create class testVertexB extends V;
        create class testVertexC extends V;

        --Define EdgeA that connects 2 vertexes -A and B
        create class testEdgeA extends E;
        create property testEdgeA.in link testVertexA;
        create property testEdgeA.out link testVertexB;

        --Define EdgeB that connects EdgeA and vertex C - is this possible?
        create class testEdgeB extends E;
        create property testEdgeB.in link testVertexC;
        create property testEdgeB.out link testEdgeA;
```

Next, we put in some data, to see if this works at all:
    orientdb > insert into testVertexA;

```
Inserted record '[testVertexA#225:0 v1]' in 0.000000 sec(s).

orientdb > insert into testVertexB;

Inserted record '[testVertexB#233:0 v1]' in 0.016000 sec(s).

orientdb > insert into testVertexC;

Inserted record '[testVertexC#241:0 v1]' in 0.000000 sec(s).

orientdb > insert into testEdgeA set in=#225:0, out=#233:0;

Inserted record '[testEdgeA#249:0{in:#225:0,out:#233:0} v1]' in 0.000000 sec(s).

orientdb > insert into testEdgeB set in=#241:0, out=#249:0;

Inserted record '[testEdgeB#257:0{in:#241:0,out:#249:0} v1]' in 0.000000 sec(s).

orientdb > select from testEdgeB;

+----+------+---------+------+------+
|#   |@RID  |@CLASS   |in    |out   |
+----+------+---------+------+------+
|0   |#257:0|testEdgeB|#241:0|#249:0|
+----+------+---------+------+------+

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.0 sec(s).

orientdb > select from  #241:0

+----+------+-----------+
|#   |@RID  |@CLASS     |
+----+------+-----------+
|0   |#241:0|testVertexC|
+----+------+-----------+

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.0 sec(s).
orientdb > select from  #249:0

+----+------+---------+------+------+
|#   |@RID  |@CLASS   |in    |out   |
+----+------+---------+------+------+
|0   |#249:0|testEdgeA|#225:0|#233:0|
+----+------+---------+------+------+

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.0 sec(s).
```

Can someone affirm this . Thanks